# Sorting values from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need the user to enter 6 numbers and the smallest of these 6 numbers is output.
Here is an example of the code but for some reason it does not sort in order:

```
x = [] 
x.append(input())
x.append(input())
x.append(input())
x.append(input())
x.append(input())
x.append(input())
x.sort()
smallest = x[0]
print(x)
print(smallest)
```

Comment: What does it sort by instead?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post example input, the expected output, and the actual output, if any.

Comment: I assume you wanted to sort as `int` not as `str` so change to `x.append(int(intput()))` or `x.sort(key = lambda i: int(i))`

Comment: if you are simply looking for the smallest number you can use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)

Comment: i need sort a 14
6
5
9
23
4

Answer (score 4):

using input() will give you a string unless you place int() around it. The sort function will then sort lexicographically instead of numerically. Change it to:

```
for i in range(6):
     x.append(int(input))
```

This should work as long as the input is guaranteed to be an integer

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the input to int before using append, the you can sort.

```
x.append(int(input()))
```

But if you want to get the smallest value you can use the min() fuction

```
x.append(int(input()))
smallest = min(x)
print(smallest)
```